# Node.js - Request: Specifying custom agent that can handle http & https

Tags: node.js, request

I'm using `request.defaults(..)` to - amongst other things - set a custom http agent for my requests (setting up `maxSockets` and `keepAlive`).

```
const agent = new http.Agent({
        keepAlive: true,
        maxSockets: 42
      })
const requestWithCustomAgent = request.defaults({
        agent,
        json: true,
        headers: {
          'User-Agent': 'amazing agent'
        }        
      })
```

When accessing a URL with scheme `https` this errors with `Error: Protocol "https:" not supported. Expected "http:"`. Vice-versa for `https.Agent` and scheme `http`.

Is there any way to "tell" request to handle `http` request with one agent and `https` with another?

One could invest some unicorn blood and do dark magic like:

```
if(url.startsWith('https') {/* use on agent */} else { /* use the other */}
```

But that feels hack'ish.

Is something like:

```
const requestWithCustomAgent = request.defaults({
    agents: {
       'http': httpAgent,
       'https': httpsAgent
    },
    json: true,
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'amazing agent'
    }        
  })
```

possible?

Help appreciated ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `agentOptions` instead of passing an `http(s).Agent` instance, `request` will create an agent for you for each scheme that is used:

```
const requestWithCustomAgent = request.defaults({
  agentOptions : {
    keepAlive  : true,
    maxSockets : 42
  },
  json    : true,
  headers : {
    'User-Agent': 'amazing agent'
  }        
})
```

Comment: Sounds more like what the OP is looking for

Comment: Nice, so the restrictions (like maxSockets, etc) would apply on a "per scheme" basis? And e.g. the http agent would just ignore options like "cert", "key", etc.

Comment: This worked for me as well. I am now confused, however, as to the purpose of using a `pool` agent instead of just doing this.

Comment: @Aarmora to be honest, I have no idea how `pool` differs from `agent`. The documentation isn't very clear about it.